# Enable Databricks Cluster logs via global init script

Tags: databricks

I want to setup [Cluster log delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#cluster-log-delivery) for all the clusters (new or old) in my workspace via global init script.

I tried to add the underlying spark properties via custom spark conf - `/databricks/driver/conf/00-custom-spark.conf` (see below). But this is not working. May be these properties are set for display purpose only.

```
cat <<EOF >/databricks/driver/conf/00-custom-ud-spark.conf
[driver] {
    "spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterLogDeliveryEnabled" = "true"
    "spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterLogDestination" = "dbfs:/cluster-logs"
}
EOF
```

Any pointers to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Reached out to Databricks team and they said this is not possible. Even the init scripts logs are available only if the cluster logging is enabled first. So, enabling at a later state has no impact.